# How do I use Loki's small object allocator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++-loki

I need to use Loki's small object allocator but I am very confused as to how it works. I've read the documentation and lots of forums but it doesnt make sense: some of them say to use the stl, others use custom allocators. I just need to be able to test its performance with allocating and deallocating objects of different sizes. Could someone please provide a small example of how to use it?

Comment: Have you read Modern C++ Design? There's an entire chapter on it there.

Comment: Yep, section 4.9 but I dont understand how the smallobject and smallobjectallocator fit together. I thought the allocator is supposed to remove the usage of new/delete operators but how do I create objects to pass to the allocator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, best I got was to make Loki's Small Object Allocator compliant with the STL. To do this I just created a wrapper class for the SmallObjAllocator class in Loki according to http://www.codeproject.com/kb/cpp/allocator.aspx?fid=16541&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&tid=1677312

Answer (score 3):

If you visit the Loki project,you might don't want to use SmallObject.It runs slower than default new.I don't know why,but some guys talked here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/loki-lib/forums/forum/93009/topic/3828398

Comment: Nothing in his question suggests he shouldn't use it for what he's doing. The most important use for object pools is to prevent memory fragmentation.

Comment: -1 this is misleading. The linked discussion only states that in that specific (corner) case Loki was slower. "It runs slower than default new" should at least be changed to "In some cases it runs slower than default new", although that can generally be said of all allocators.