# Does STL Vector use 'new' and 'delete' for memory allocation by default?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector, allocation

I am working on a plugin for an application, where the memory should be allocated by the Application and keep track of it. Hence, memory handles should be obtained from the host application in the form of buffers and later on give them back to the application. Now, I am planning on using STL Vectors and I am wondering what sort of memory allocation does it use internally.

Does it use 'new' and 'delete' functions internally? If so, can I just overload 'new' and 'delete' with my own functions? Or should I create my own template allocator which looks like a difficult job for me since I am not that experienced in creating custom templates.

Any suggestions/sample code are welcome. Memory handles can be obtained from the application like this

```
void* bufferH = NULL;

bufferH = MemReg()->New_Mem_Handle(size_of_buffer);
MemReg()->Dispose_Mem_Handle(bufferH); //Dispose it
```

Comment: For creating your own allocator see this classic by Matt Austern: http://www.drdobbs.com/184403759

Comment: @sbi: I haven't read that yet, but recall that allocator semantics changed significantly in C++11. Are you sure that classic is still relevant today? (That is not a rhetorical question but a real one.)

Comment: @einpoklum That is a 6 year old comment. We have two new standard versions and another one on the horizon. Of course things might have changed since then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`vector` uses `std::allocator` by default, and `std::allocator` is required to use global operator new (that is, `::operator new(size_t)`) to obtain the memory (20.4.1.1). However, it isn't required to call it exactly once per call to `allocator::allocate`.

So yes, if you replace global operator new then `vector` will use it, although not necessarily in a way that really allows your implementation to manage memory "efficiently". Any special tricks you want to use could, in principle, be made completely irrelevant by `std::allocator` grabbing memory in 10MB chunks and sub-allocating.

If you have a particular implementation in mind, you can look at how its `vector` behaves, which is probably good enough if your planned allocation strategy is inherently platform-specific.

Comment: Other containers can benefit from custom allocators, though.  For certain applications, a pool allocator can drastically improve the performance of node-based containers like `std::map`.

Comment: Small object allocation is also one of Alexandrescu's favourite topics - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707909/how-do-i-use-lokis-small-object-allocator

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I shouldn't have used the word 'efficient'. I meant that the application is supposed to allocate 'all' the memory and keep track of it no matter of its size or efficiency. But from your comment, it looks like overloading new and delete should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

STL containers use an allocator they are given at construction time, with a [default allocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8z741y5(v=VS.100).aspx) that uses `operator new` and `operator delete`.

If you find the default is not working for you, you can provide a custom allocator that conforms to the container's requirements.  There are some real-world examples cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826569/compelling-examples-of-custom-c-stl-allocators).

I would measure performance using the default first, and optimize only if you really need to.  The allocator abstraction offers you a relatively clean way to fine-tune here without major redesign.  How you use the `vector` could have far more performance impact than the underlying allocator (`reserve()` in advance, avoid insert and removal in the middle of the range of elements, handle copy construction of elements efficiently - the standard *caveats*).

Comment: @James, @GMan: There are a couple of specific aspects that are unspecified though -- particularly, when and how often `std::allocator` uses `::operator new` to obtain memory, and how (or even if) the `hint` parameter is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve. I do reserve the vector in advance and avoid removal and insert of middle range elements. But I wasn't sure overloading new and delete would make it use the memory allocated by the host application. My apologies for using the word 'efficient'.

Comment: No apology needed, writing for the broader audience as well as to you... it's possible you need to clarify the memory ownership to get best specific answer.  What do you plan to store, where does its memory come from, how does it get released?  A minimal sample code would help.

Comment: Sample code added to illustrate how to get handles from the application. I plan on to store float values (OpenGL vertices).

Comment: @gutsblow - if this is your only path to allocate memory, then I can't see how you can avoid writing a custom allocator to encapsulate the `host_new_handle` and `host_dispose_handle` APIs.

Comment: So, if overload both 'new' and 'delete' with functions that encapsulate host_new_handle and host_dispose_handle, doesn't that mean STL also gets memory from those functions?

Comment: My idea was to create a header that contains those functions and force include it in every file. Not sure, if its the best way to do it but certainly the easiest way (only if it works).

Comment: Yes but I am not sure of the scope of such a change given that you are a library in a host application - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007274/a-library-forces-global-overloads-of-new-delete-on-me.  Why not create your own allocator - a class template that wraps `std::allocator` but overloads `operator new` and `operator delete` at the class level?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll sure check it out. Yes, making a custom allocator is the right thing to do, so I'll go ahead with it even if it takes some time.

Comment: Good luck - there are plenty of models online, just make sure you pick one that works to follow.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` uses the `unitialized_*` functions to construct its elements from raw memory (using placement new). It allocates storage using whatever allocator it was created with, and by default, that allocator uses `::operator new(size_t)` and `::operator delete(void *p)` directly (i.e., not a type specific `operator new`).

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079) article, "The concept of allocators was originally introduced to provide an abstraction for different memory models to handle the problem of having different pointer types on certain 16-bit operating systems (such as near, far, and so forth)" ...

"The standard provides an allocator that internally uses the global operators 'new' and 'delete'"

The author also points out the alocator interface isn't that scary. As Neil Buchanan would say, "try it yourself!"

Answer (score 2):

The actual `std::allocator` has been optimized for a rather large extent of size objects.  It isn't the best when it comes to allocating many small objects nor is it the best for many large objects.  That being said, it also wasn't written for multi-threaded applications.

May I suggest, before attempting to write your own you check out the [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/) allocator if you're going the multi-threaded route.  (Or you can check out the equally appealing [Intel TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) page too.)