# what type should i put in a function definition when using a vector<double>?

Tags: c++

I have a function, prototyped as below:

```
double gradeCalc (double midterm, double final, const vector<double>& hwGrades);
```

in my code I pass the variable homework, declared as

```
vector<double> homework;
```

into the third argument. I get the below error:

```
undefined reference to `gradeCalc(double, double, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >)'
```

In the textbook I'm working from, the function prototype is the same, yet there is no mention of this error. It seems the type of homework is not what I thought it was. What have I done wrong? (and what is an allocator for that matter?)

**edit**
full function definition below as requested:

```
double gradeCalc (double midterm, double final, const vector<double> & hwGrades) {
    if (hwGrades.size() == 0) {
    throw domain_error("homework grades list empty");
    }

    double median = vdMedian(hwGrades);
    return 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * median;
}
```

**edit #2**
found. silly typographical error. would still be interested to know what an allocator is. happy to ask in a seperate question.

Comment: Did you actually define the function?  Providing a [mcve] will help.

Comment: where is the `gradeCalc` defined?

Comment: gradeCalc is defined in the program, I was trying to keep it minimal as it seems to be some kind of type mismatch? rather than whats inside the function. in any case i'll add it now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You can upload the whole code to sites like pastebin. Having a working example would help.

Comment: Shouldn't the prototype have double for return type?

Comment: This question does not provide enough information to answer it.

Comment: found! missing ampersand in prototype. not a strange type mismatch as it seemed. would still be interested to know why the type of homework is not the same as i declared it with.

Comment: That means your declaration (not "prototype") is _not_ as you showed us. Please copy/paste your [MCVE] instead of wasting our time

Comment: _"would still be interested to know what an allocator is. happy to ask in a seperate question."_ Yes, that should be a separate question, but no, you don't need to ask it again: [What are allocators and when is their use necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848186/what-are-allocators-and-when-is-their-use-necessary) Note that question was closed, so it might be that it's considered too general for SO. But see also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254811/memory-management-stdallocator and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826569/compelling-examples-of-custom-c-allocators

Answer (score 0):

The `vector` template is defined as

```
template<class _Ty, class _Alloc = allocator<_Ty> >
class vector: public _Vector_alloc<_Vec_base_types<_Ty, _Alloc> >
```

Note the deafult value for the second template parameter.

So when you write this

```
std::vector<double> homework;
```

it's actually the same as

```
std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> homework;
```